# youtube data api not working with videorecordingdetails - show error 400 unexpectedPart

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I include VideoRecordingDetails while inserting a video through youtube data api, it shows me the below error:-

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.part",
    "location" : "part",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "{0}",
    "reason" : "unexpectedPart"
  } ],
  "message" : "{0}"
}
```

But after commenting the below line, its working fine.

ytvideo.setRecordingDetails(recordingDetails);

Please help me how I can set recording date  of a video. Here is my code which is not working:-

```
VideoRecordingDetails recordingDetails = new VideoRecordingDetails();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(vdata.getYtRecordDate());
recordingDetails.setRecordingDate(dt);

ytvideo.setRecordingDetails(recordingDetails);
```

Comment: Have you checked if there's a value of `recordingDetails` object? The `recordingDetails` object is not public for all videos, so if a video doesn't have these attributes available, nothing will be returned.

Comment: Yes I was missing recordingDetails in below line

Comment: Then that means you will have a bad request. It would be nice to have a null checker for this.